Can players take on the form of a mob either version of Minecraft
I want to make a "Kill me if you can" mini-game on Minecraft, and a trick I want to do is to take on the form of a pig and run into a pen of pigs so my friends think I'm just a normal pig and pass me by. Is there a way I can transform myself into any entity I chose and go back to my original form? Before I start making the game, can I use this method in Java and/or Bedrock?
Also is it possible to cameo as a block?

Does it needs to be commands? What's wrong with /tag the "it", making them invisible and then constantly /tping a pig to wherever "it" is and in whatever direction "it" is looking in?

Like those fake Koopas in the classic Super Mario Bros.? Just changes at the last second? I could do something like that. I want to create a funny moment of a pig attacking players and running away like a player.

An April fools version had this feature.

@FabianRöling lol. Is there an article on that? That would be funny to read.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bottle_of_Entity

Oh! There is more? Sad you can't use these anymore. Mojang should have kept these as debug items like the Giant.

The Vanilla Way
Run the following:
# tag someone and something as it
/tag @s it
/tag {entity-guid} disguise

Put the following (minus the comments) in a repeating command block chain:
# make you invisible
/effect @a[tag=it] minecraft:invisibility infinite 1 true
# constantly tp 'disguise' to 'it' (relative is to 'it')
/execute as @e[tag=it] run /tp @e[tag=disguise] ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

The Modded Way
With mods, you can make a client/server display a fake mob, and have more fine controls over your fake mob.

https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/mobdisguises (Client-side Forge/Fabric Mod)

